# Crashlytics and XCode 6.3 - unable to find 'codesign' tool via xcrun

Tags: xcode, xcode6, crashlytics

My app archive is created successfully, but Crashlytics fails to upload it for testing, and provides the following messages:

```
Unable to find 'codesign' tool via xcrun

Make sure that command line developer tools are installed and that `xcode-select` 
is pointing to a valid developer directory.
```

Command line tools are installed. XCode->Preferences->Locations is pointing to XCode 6.3 tools.

`xcode-select -p` displays `/Applications/Xcode-6.3.app/Contents/Developer`, which is a valid developer directory.

Any ideas? Crashlytics guys, are you out there?

Comment: What's the output of the command `xcrun --find codesign` from `Terminal`?

Comment: The codesign tool path looks right, although my XCode path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, so maybe the addition of 6.3 is the problem.

Comment: I tried that, but no deal. Same error...

Comment: Maybe try [resetting the XCode path](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) or setting the `env`. BTW - Are you using the latest Crashlytics?

Comment: I tried updating Crashlytics. Yikes, that's a very ugly process. I was forced to update to 'Fabric', which [didn't work at all](https://twittercommunity.com/t/stuck-on-build-your-project-after-upgrading-crashlytics-to-fabric/31428), and managed to somehow break my project entirely. 

At this point I can't get Fabric to work, and I can't reinstall the old version of Crashlytics. Both fail in the same way - hang while waiting for build to complete.

Comment: error occurs when you rename Xcode.app to XcodeX.X.X.app or smth.

Answer (score 8):

Just run `sudo xcrun --find codesign` from the termimal and accept the licenses.